# Return Boolean value from Grails Tablib?

Tags: grails, gsp

I created a custom Grails tablib:

```
  def hasRole = { attrs, body ->
    boolean result = false 
    if (attrs.roles) {
      if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted(attrs.roles)) {
        result = true
      }
    }
    out << result  
  }
```

This can be used like this:

```
${cust.hasRole(roles:'ROLE_ADMIN') ? 'yes' : 'no' }
```

The problem is that the comparison alway results to `yes`. It seams that the expression is not evaluated correctly.

The returning class type of hasRole is `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer`.

**How do I get the above expression evaluated correctly such that `hasRole()` returns a boolean value?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is going to be the use of `returnObjectForTags` in your TagLib. By default a tag library outputs information to the output writer (`out`). In your case you want to do something like this:

```
package example

class FooTagLib {
  static namespace = 'something'
  static returnObjectForTags = ['hasRole']

  def hasRole = { attrs, body ->
    boolean result = false
    ...
    return result
  }
}
```

As you can see `returnObjectForTags` is a static list of the methods/closures which you want to return actual objects for and don't expect to be modifying the output stream directly.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!